# how to use R to transfer hourly passenger OD data to od matrix

Tags: r, matrix, reshape

I'm trying to transfer hourly passenger OD data to OD matrix.

My current dataframe looks something like this:

```
Hour  Ostation Dstation  Passengers
8      A       B          2
8      A       C          3
8      A       D          4
8      B       C          5
8      B       D          6
8      C       D          1
10     A       B          4
10     A       C          5 
10     A       D          6 
10     B       C          1
10     B       D          2
10     C       D          3
```

And I'd like for `HOUR = 8`:

```
    A   B   C   D
A       
B   2
C   3   5
D   4   6   1
```

And `HOUR = 10`:

```
    A   B   C   D
A       
B   4
C   5   1
D   6   2   3
```

I use `split` and `table`:

```
ODdata$Ostation <- factor(ODdata$Ostation)
ODdata$Dstation <- factor(ODdata$Dstation)
ODtable <-lapply(split(ODdata, ODdata$Hour), 
                 function(x) table(x$Ostation, x$Dstation))
```

I can get the OD matrix, but the value is counts, not `Passengers`.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `dcast` from `reshape2` in place of `table`. Set `drop = F` to keep all factor levels in the output matrices.

```
library(reshape2)
ODtable <-lapply(split(ODdata, ODdata$Hour), 
                 function(x) dcast(Dstation ~ Ostation , data = x, 
                                   value.var = "Passengers", drop = FALSE))
ODtable

#$`8`
#  Dstation  A  B  C  D
#1        A NA NA NA NA
#2        B  2 NA NA NA
#3        C  3  5 NA NA
#4        D  4  6  1 NA
# 
#$`10`
#  Dstation  A  B  C  D
#1        A NA NA NA NA
#2        B  4 NA NA NA
#3        C  5  1 NA NA
#4        D  6  2  3 NA
```

### sample data

```
ODdata <- data.frame(Hour = c(rep(8,6), rep(10,6)),
             Ostation = factor(c("A","A","A","B","B","C","A","A","A","B","B","C"),
                                   levels = c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D')),
             Dstation = factor(c("B","C","D","C","D","D","B","C","D","C","D","D"), 
                                   levels = c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D')),
             Passengers = c(2,3,4,5,6,1,4,5,6,1,2,3))
```